# Cannot install any APK file due to "Out of Space" misleading error (plenty of space)

Tags: internal-storage, custom-roms, installation, insufficient-memory, apk

I know there are tons of questions about this, but I have tried many possible solutions to no avail. I believe the "Out of space" error is misleading...

I have a problem: **I cannot install any .apk file** no matter what I try... I can install apps using **Play Store** though.
When I tap on an APK file in any file explorer, Android Package Installer launches. I tap the INSTALL button but I always got the following error:

> Out of space {AnyAPKApp} couldn't be installed. Free up some space and
>   try again.

I have *plenty* of space, but even a tiny 248 KB APK won't install with the same argument...

This is the only problem I have with the ROM and it is very frustrating...
First, the details of my case:

- *Device:* Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime+ SM-G532M, alias Galaxy J2 Prime (Xtreme detects my device as *Model Number:* SM-G950F)
- *Android:* 6.0.1
- *ROM:* [Xtreme Ultimate V6.0 (15.07.2018)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j2/development/rom-xtreme-ultimate-beta-v3-xtreme-team-t3763904)
- *TWRP:* 3.0.2-0
- *Magisk:* v17.1
- *Magisk Manager:* 6.0.1 (151)
- *Storage:* Adoptable
- *Internal storage:* 7.02 GB used of 8.00 GB
- *SD card:* 9.09 GB used of 14.70 GB
- *Root Essentials "View storage used":* 9759/15787 MB (62%)
- *DiskUsage analysis:* /system = 2.94 GiB; Free space 1.61 GiB

I've already done my homework and tried all of the following to no avail:

1. Move all movable apps to SD
2. Enable Adoptable storage
3. Wipe *Dalvik / ART Cache* and *Cache* partitions with TWRP
4. Full clean with *SD Maid PRO*
5. Force move apps to SD using *SD Maid PRO*
6. Uninstall *Google Play Services* and *Google Play Store* updates
7. Overcome *unauthorized device* issue while using ADB
8. Trying to install APK using ADB (e.g. adb install someApp.apk). I got: `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]`
9. Delete `/data/log` contents as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19967123/1119621)
10. Attempt to install in `Safe Mode`
11. Using Termux and the `df` command, I got the following output and there is free space in each partition: [image: <code>df</code> output]
12. Using `pm install test.apk` in a terminal emulator (*Termux*) I got `[INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]`. Using full path `pm install /storage/emulated/0/Download/test.apk` I got the same error: `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]`

The problem still remains. I think this is not really related to the full storage device error, I have plenty and the error seems misleading. It has to be something else...
I gave as much info as I thought it was useful. If more is needed, just tell me to share it.

I hope you can give me some advice to try to overcome this annoying issue.

*P.S. I'll add more attempts to my list as I try them.*

Comment: Curious if your SD card is partitioned?  Also with which file system format it has (ntfs, fat32, etc..)?

Comment: @CzarMatt If I understand correctly `adb shell mount` output, it is `sdcardfs`, right? `/mnt/expand/d02821cc-6e14-4015-ae94-1bbd69368dce/media /mnt/runtime/default/emulated sdcardfs rw`

Comment: @CzarMatt I followed the steps of `Root Essentials` to use my SD card as Adoptable Storage if that's meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions on the directories where the software will be installed (and the directories leading up to the installation directory)?

Do the application(s) you are using to install the APK's have the install software right denied?  With LineageOS, this is handled by Privacy Guard.  I use X-plore: try installing it (from Play Store) and see if you can install with it.  With LineageOS, you would be prompted to allow X-plore to install software.  (It may request root privilege too.)  Perhaps you inadvertently denied the privilege earlier to your other programs (though you mention trying with adb)?

My suggestion is to backup and try reformatting the sdcard (or better yet use a new one) with the default filesystem using the built-in system utility.  On my phone, this is handled by System Preferences -> Storage (I believe).  Don't make any further changes, and try to install the APK's.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. About the permissions, I download the APK files with Chrome browser to `/storage/emulated/0/Download`. According to SD Maid Pro, the permissions on the directory are `rwxrwx--x` (`/0` as well. `/emulated` has `rwx--x--x` and `/storage` has `rwxr-xr-x`) which seems fine to me. All downloads including APK files have these permissions: `rw-rw----` I even tried to set 777 permissions to an APK and install it with `adb` to test , but nothing. I'll add this to my attempt list. More comments to come about your answer/suggestions...

Comment: About the applications used to install, I've tried with the following (all with root privilegies): _Root Essentials (Root Browser)_, _SD Maid PRO (Explorer)_, _Total Commander_ and now _X-plore_All of them launch **Android's Package Installer**. I've also tried with `adb install test.apk`and nothing... Using `pm install test.apk` in a terminal emulator (Termux) I got `[INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]`